# Append text to iFrame body where users mouse is "blinking"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append a face icon to the body of a iframe. The problem I am having is that it is put at the end of the body, not where the user has the insertion point.

Here is the code I have so far,

```
 <iframe style=""name="content" id="content" width="758" height="200" onload="javascript:load();"></iframe>


function angleFace()
{
$("#content").contents().find("body").append('<img title="Angle" src="/media/angle.png" alt="Angle">');
}
```

I want the face to be put wherever the users insertion point is at. Right now the face is being put at the end of the document.

Side note - You type into the iFrame then on the submit it is transfered to the textarea then entered into the database.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want it at the end of the body? or right after the textbox that the user is on?

Comment: Also, what is the source of the iframe?

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from your site or from a different website?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.find("body")` with `.find("*:focus")`. That should give you the element that has focus within the iframe.

Then add an element after it using the `.after()` method.

```
$("#content").contents().find("*:focus").after('<img title="Angle" src="/media/angle.png" alt="Angle">');
```

Comment: What is happening? Console log?

Comment: When I replaced .find("*:focus") with .find("body") it placed onto the iframe. When I changed it back to .find("*:focus") nothing happend

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from your site or from a different website?

Comment: This worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/JDZ2y/ There must be some details that you're not providing.

Comment: the iFrame itself is the textfield. Theres nothing inside it